# Exact strings do not match in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

What did I want to do?

I was reading file names with various organ names in their file endings and there are many such files using glob.glob('filename/**/blabla')

Later, I tried to match a particular string if present inside the filename using IN operator. like

"ADRENALGLAND(LEFT).NRRD" IN "blabla/blabla/blabla/blablabla_ADRENALGLAND(LEFT).NRRD"

It worked for other filenames with the same ending whereas it did not work for a few.
To debug, I was trying to match if visually the same filename endings from two files are the same programmatically, but they are not!!! why?

For debug, I tried to match string to string. Like below. But I saw a peculiar thing while comparing strings in python.
Can anyone tell me what is the difference here?

**

> 'ADRENALGLAND(LEFT).NRRD' == 'АDRENALGLAND(LEFT).NRRD' => False !!!

** [image]

I bring it down to this part where 'A's do not match whereas others matched properly.

[image]

Comment: are you sure they are just 1 character. Maybe there are spaces

Comment: @canbax, Yes I double checked. There are no spaces or something.

Comment: try to copy-paste the 'A' s and check `int` values using `ord()` function. Maybe somehow they are different characters

Comment: @canbax, yes you are correct, one gave 65, the usual ASCII code for A, whereas the other one gave 1040.  But if that's a special character from some other literature script, how it looks the same?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook shows you the characters. You might report a bug to them. I don't know how it happends.

Comment: Thanks.. I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @canbax, I checked the underline ASCII value for both the character and found that they are different. One gave 65 (Normal ASCII Code for English Alphabet 'A') whereas the other one gave 1040.

You can use `ord()` to get the ASCII int value of a character.

Although the int values are different, visually they look the same, which might be an issue from the jupyter notebook side.

**Final Solution:** `Replaced the fancy A with the normal A in the file.`

Comment: @canbax Answer it and I can make your answer the accepted one. I thought it just a comment away to solve the issue and no answer required. So I answered it. Go ahead, post an answer.

Comment: Nope thank you. I want the upvotes that I deserved. It was just a joke ;)